# How to handle with foreign languages?

Tags: html, database, zend-framework, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm developing a brazilian website which has to support foreign characters like `á, à, ó, í ú, ê, etc`. It also uses AJAX so I thought better to use charset `UTF-8` 'cause I always get the � character and I don't know how to fix this.

My navigation menu appears correctly when using `UTF-8` (since it's querying the database to render the whole menu), but I don't know how it does. Here are some screenshots of the database and how it renders:
[image: The database][image]

So far so good. The trouble is that I started using Zend_Navigation for rendering breadcrumbs and I don't know what to do to get over with the � character i'm getting:
[image: the breadcrumb][image]

What should I do? Change the charset to ISO-8858-1? I have already done this but it appears everything wrong like this:

[image]

## EDIT

In addition, when I change it to `miss&atilde;o` for example it displays `miss&atilde;o` instead of `missão`. Besides, I can't change it manually 'cause it is in the database, I need sort of a function which will handle this

## EDIT 2

I changed the special character in my database like `Ã§Ã£` to `&ccedil;&atilde;` and now the HTML is rendering fine. Although, I'm using the Zend_Navigation for breadcrumb and it's rendering `miss&atilde;o` instead of `missão` just like this:

[image]

I also wrote a XML file using Zend_Config_Writer_Xml and I see it printed `<label>Informa&#xE7;&#xF5;es</label>` instead of `<label>Informações</label>`. Just in case that helps

How should I proceed?

Comment: Your database encoding should do the job. I guess you have a problem with your html header here (so does phpmyadmin). Try to put something like: 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> to your html header... , this is what worked for me for chinese websites...

Comment: I already have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in my website header, and what should do my database encoding? It's `latin1` now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a really good article that helped me when I started web development. I work in a multilingual environment so I bump into this stuff constantly (just to add to how great the article was :)

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

I always make sure that my files are saved in UTF8 line encoding, that my php header files declare the charset as utf8, that my db uses utf8_general_ci for it's collation, and that my html head tag contains the meta tag declaring the content as utf8. I think that covers it.

HTH :)

edit: just to add (to be more aimed at your specific problem) check to see if your PHP code treats your results as utf8. The data might be stored correctly on the DB but could be converted when it's being served.

Comment: While a little long, this article is quite interesting. I think his problem is the encoding of the file itself (which used to be my problem ¬_¬) Anyway, if the OP uses Eclipse (as he should using ZF), he can modify the encoding all files in his workspace in the preference -> workspace and here you can change file encoding.

Comment: I don't think it's the file since I think he's pulling those menu items from the DB (I assume). At least now he has a check list to go through to debug it though :)

Comment: What would be the correct form to store it in the database? Do I have to see `çã` in phpMyAdmin instead of `Ã§Ã£`? Or &ccedil;&atilde; should do?

Comment: utf8_general_ci is the collation I usually use. In this case you'd want everything to use UTF8.If you're seeing the actual HTML codes I'd guess that you are using htmlentities() on your data before storing it. I'm not sure how to answer your second question though, I'm guess phpmyadmin uses utf8 so you should see the correct character (so you should see "é" if you saved "é")

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your database uses the UTF-8 charset AND your database connection (the encoding in which the chars are transferred between MySQL and your PHP code) is UTF-8 (see [this post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php#89593) for reference).

Also note, that some string operations in PHP break UTF8 encoded strings ebcause they work on the assumption "1 char = byte" which is not true with UTF 8. htmlspecialchars won't work with UTF-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing .php file encoding - open up .php file and save it (or overwrite it) as utf8 file. Hope it helps.