# How to enable other language letters in html?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I just want to know how to enable other language letters in html.

Example:

[image: In visual studio code]

[image: In web]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code, copyright symbol © shown as � and saved as ï¿½ or �](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764789/vs-code-copyright-symbol-shown-as-and-saved-as-%c3%af-%c2%bd-or)

Comment: Do you have a web server? What `Content-Type` header is it sending?

Comment: You can refer to this kind of question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135374/how-to-handle-with-foreign-languages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Special Characters (foreign languages)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741993/html-special-characters-foreign-languages)

Answer (score 0):

The W3C document [Character encodings for beginners](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding) and the documents it links to is a good starting point for learning about how to solve this.

In short:

- Pick a character encoding. This should be UTF-8 unless you have a really good reason to pick something different.
- Configure your editor to use that encoding (this is usually done in the SaveAs dialog box)
- Specify the encoding in your HTML document with `<meta charset="utf-8">` near the top of the `<head>`
- Specify the encoding in your HTTP response headers (how you do that depends on your HTTP server and/or server side programming language): `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`